# Data image url loading but displaying nothing

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas

Im using a div to canvas converter in pure javascript it displays on canvas but when I do canvas.toDataUrl() it returns an error and after I tried to fix it the outputted image is blank heres the code

```js
function ConvertElement(container) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var dom = document.querySelector(container);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var data =
        "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='" +
        width +
        "px' height='" +
        height +
        "px'>" +
        "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
        "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font: 15px sans-serif;'>" +
        dom.innerHTML +
        "</div>" +
        "</foreignObject>" +
        "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    var svg = new Blob([data], {
        type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
    });
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function() {
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            dom.remove();
        },
        false
    );
    img.src = url;
    ctx.canvas.width = width;
    ctx.canvas.height = height;
}
var Newtest = `<div class='test'><div class='a'></div></div>`;
var style = `.a {background:red; width: 100px; height: 100px}`;
document.body.innerHTML += Newtest;
var add = document.createElement("style");
add.innerHTML = style;
document.querySelector(".test").appendChild(add);
ConvertElement(".test");
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code has `var dom = document.querySelector(container);`, but what is container ?

Comment: Container is the input string in the function it works like `function a(text) { alert(text)`

Comment: Missed the ConvertElement(container) part. My bad.